# Writing gridded NetCDF format CF Convention from a 4 dimensional Array in Java

Tags: java, netcdf, array

I am using Unidata NetCDF Java library to write NetCDF, its being written in the classical format, but I want to write it as a gridded NetCDF file (as THREDDS / WMS are unable to read a classic NetCDF file for serving WMS requests)

I have a 4 dimensional Array of dimensions like this

Temperature[TIME][DEPTH][LAT][LONG], how can I write it using NetCdfCFWriter and using GridDataSets?

Answer (score 0):

For time variable of classical netCDF file, add attribute of units with value "seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0 0:00". This actually worked for me.
**Note: Modify date time according to your dataset values.**